# Cannot enter values for two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++

I'm doing an assignment for a class and it's fairly routine. I've done this before in Java so it's not entirely new to me, however, I'm not entirely sure what's wrong here.

Basically I need to enter information for several row/columns and then print the sum of the column, all of that isn't particularly difficult. However, every time I print my array's contents everything is 1, no matter what.

I'm not sure what's wrong, if someone can tell me why I'd appreciate it.

Oh, forgot to mention, I am using **g++** for compiling.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLUMNS = 3;

void setupMatrix() {
    // Setup matrix
    double array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

    // Needed? Wouldn't think so.
    // for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
    //      for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
    //              array[i][j] = 0.0;
    //      }
    // }

    // Get array information from user
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
            printf("Row %d\n", (i + 1));
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
                    printf("Column %d ", (j + 1));
                    cin >> array[i][j];
            }
    }

    // Print array so I can see what's up first
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
            // Row & column separation
            printf("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", array[j][i]);
            }
    }

}

int main () {
    setupMatrix();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: homework tag is now deprecated

Comment: What should I use instead, if anything?

Comment: @Casey Nothing. Whether this is homework is irrelevant in the current form of the question (this is a *good* thing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First dimension of the array is ROWS and second is COLUMNS, you got the cycles order wrong. Also to print double use format specifier `%lf` in the printf. I don't see why you decided to use `printf` when you read using `cin`, better use `cout` for consistency and as this is the typical way to print in `C++`

Comment: are you sure %lf should be used? lf is for long double according to [some sources](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: @DariuszWawer AFAK `%f` is float, `%lf` is double and `%llf`(or `%Lf` on other compilers) is long double. Tested through many years of experience.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had completely forgotten to double check the proper way to print doubles with `printf`. Would never have thought of that, same goes for the column and row sizes. Just curious, is using `printf` considered bad practice? As I like to use it where I can since it's a lot quicker to write statements with it than `cout`.

Comment: @CaseyWeed I personally use printf quite often for the exact same reason, because I do a lot of IO operations. I don't think it's a bad practise just saying you would not have done the error had you used cout.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. For homework/classwork I might just use `cout` first and verify that everything written is sane, and change it to printf afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
array[i][j]);
```

for "cin"and

```
array[j][i]);
```

for print: use `cout<<array[j][i]);`

Comment: Woops. Didn't notice that. Thank you.